# Does the following model design have optimization space?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, database

Should port fields be of integer or string type?

Should port fields use Boolean or enumeration types? (I'm not sure Django supports enumeration types yet)

Or do you have any better suggestions? I would appreciate it if you could write specific code!

```
from django.db import models


class Proxy(models.Model)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
    port = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField()
```